# Analytic continuation of $(x-a)^{-1/4}$?

Tags: analytic-continuation

In Landau's book on quantum mechanics an expression of the form

$$
(x-a)^{-1/4}
$$

is analytically continued around the upper half-plane along the semicircle from $0$ to $\pi$. The result stated is

$$(a-x)^{-1/4}e^{-i\pi/4}$$

How does one derive this result? Landau writes $(x-a)=\rho e^{i\phi}$ and lets $\phi$ go from $0$ to $\pi$. In this manner

$$(x-a)^{-1/4}\to \rho^{-1/4}e^{-i\phi /4}$$

but why is this not simply

$$(x-a)^{-1/4}e^{-i\pi/4}$$

at the end of the semicircle?